# Android improve performance of map of multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: java, android, performance, canvas, surfaceview

I have a working code but what I want to achieve is better FPS performance in `drawMap()` (this method is called later in custom SurfaceView's onDraw() method). The problem is of course with these huge `bitmapsAnimated` and `canvasesAnimated` objects. As a solution I would like for example to split them to smaller constructions. I guess it could much improve my FPS but I don't know how to modify my code to do this. I am also open to another improvements regarding this issue that you suggest.

```
private static final Map<Integer, Bitmap[][][]> bitmapsAnimated = new HashMap<>();
private static final Map<Integer, Canvas[][][]> canvasesAnimated = new HashMap<>();

public void init(List<Integer> animFrames) {
        for (int i = 0; i < animFrames.size(); i++) {
            runnables.add(new FrameDurationRunnable(animFrames.get(i), animsDuration.get(i)));
            bitmapsAnimated.put(i, new Bitmap[animFrames.get(i)][40][60]);
            canvasesAnimated.put(i, new Canvas[animFrames.get(i)][40][60]);
            for (int j = 0; j < animFrames.get(i); j++) {
                for (int a = 0; a < 40; a++) {
                    for (int b = 0; b < 60; b++) {
                        bitmapsAnimated.get(i)[j][a][b] = Bitmap.createBitmap(GameSurface.cellWidth, GameSurface.cellHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        canvasesAnimated.get(i)[j][a][b] = new Canvas(bitmapsAnimated.get(i)[j][a][b]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

later in loop inside another method:

```
canvasesAnimated.get(l)[frame][k][j].drawBitmap(tilesets[currentTileSetIndex], source, dest, null);
```

and finally:

```
public static void drawMap(Canvas canvas, GameSurface gs) {

    int moveX = -((GameMainSurface) gs).moveX;
    int moveY = -((GameMainSurface) gs).moveY;

    for (int i = moveX / GameSurface.cellWidth; i < (moveX / GameSurface.cellWidth) + GameSurface.VISIBLE_COLUMN_NUMBER + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = moveY / GameSurface.cellHeight; j < (moveY / GameSurface.cellHeight) + GameSurface.VISIBLE_ROW_NUMBER + 1; j++) {

            for (int k = 0; k < bitmapsAnimated.size(); k++) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapsAnimated.get(k)[((FrameDurationRunnable) runnables.get(k)).iter][i][j], i * GameSurface.cellWidth - moveX, j * GameSurface.cellHeight - moveY, null);
            }
        }
    }

    if (!isIterStarted) {
        iterTmxFrames();
        isIterStarted = true;
    }
}


private static void iterTmxFrames() {
    for (int i = 0; i < runnables.size(); i++) {
        handler.postDelayed(runnables.get(i), animsDuration.get(i));
    }
}
```